# Update method with post

Tags: javascript, angular, crud

I have to create an Update method with a post request.
But when I did it , create an another object.

this is the python code from the server for edit class

```py
def edit_schema(cls, admin: bool = False, cm: bool = False):

    if cm:

        return {
            'id': {'type': 'number', 'min': 1},
            'client': {'type': 'number', 'required': False, 'min': -1, 'forbidden': [0]},
            'led_spec': {'type': 'string', 'required': False}
        }
    elif admin:
        return {
            'id': {'type': 'number', 'min': 1},
            'client': {'type': 'number', 'required': False, 'dependencies': 'group', 'min': -1, 'forbidden': [0]},
            'name': {'type': 'string', 'required': False, 'empty': False, 'maxlength': 255},
            'led_spec': {'type': 'string', 'required': False}
        # }
    else:
        return {
            'id': {'type': 'number', 'min': 1},
            'name': {'type': 'string', 'required': False, 'empty': False, 'maxlength': 255}
        }
```

My service.ts

```
public update(fixture: Fixture){
    let body = {};
    if(fixture.name !== '' && fixture.name !== null)
      body['name'] = fixture.name;
    if(fixture.client !== -1 && fixture.client !== null)
      body['client'] = fixture.client;
    if(fixture.group !== -1 && fixture.group !== null)
      body['group'] = fixture.group;
    return this
      .post('fixture/edit', body).toPromise().then(data => {
        this._refreshNeeded$.next();
      })
}
```

and my component

````
update() {
    if (this.form.valid) {
      this.formSubmitAttempt = true;
      this.fixtureService.update(this.form.value);
      this.dialogRef.close(this.form.value);
      console.log(this.form.value)// send updated value to main component
    }
}
```
````

Comment: Assuming that you're using @angular/common/http, try `put` instead of `post`

Comment: I just need to use post instead of put because , the back end dev made it like this

Comment: A `put` request is actually `post` - a hidden form attribute/header is added by most frameworks automatically and will help the backend to determine the difference.

Comment: But the put doesn't work anymore

Comment: So the backend filters out a POST request if it is tagged as PUT? You might attach the object's ID for the backend to determine if you are trying to create or update - this is a serious architechtural problem though. On backend side. Just be prepated for accidental duplication if the ID gets lost.

Comment: Which file you need to see ? I'm very beginner

Comment: Probably more of your Python backend, because I cannot see where it determines the request type. I came here for the Javascript mostly, but please post it anyway 
because maybe someone else can help you with the Python part.